# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException Error in simple_list_item_checked

Tags: android, android-listview, indexoutofboundsexception

I create dynamical number of checkboxes (it depends on the length of array) in an Android app. I added dynamic number of checkboxes using student_array[].It works fine.

But I want to get the array of checked items from this list.

So I use **present_array[]** varible for get list of checked items from **simple_list_item_checked** list.

It works in toast for showing **item**.But adding this item to **present_array[item]** showing the ArryIndexOutOfBoundException.

Advance thanks for your help..

**This is my java file**

```
public class Tab1 extends Activity {
String [] student_array={"party","sport","music","café","education"};
String [] present_array;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
  ArrayList<String> presentlist;
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.tab1);
      ArrayAdapter<String> adapter= new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked, student_array);
      final ListView lv= (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
      lv.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
      lv.setAdapter(adapter);


      lv.setOnItemClickListener(new android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            int len = lv.getCount();
            SparseBooleanArray checked = lv.getCheckedItemPositions();
            for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
             if (checked.get(i)) {
          String item =(String) lv.getItemAtPosition(checked.keyAt(i));

         present_array[i]=item;  // ERROR WHEN ADDING STRING ARRAY //

             }          
        }
    });


      }
```

**My LogCat**

```
 07-06 06:26:49.329: E/AndroidRuntime(1328): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 07-06 06:26:49.329: E/AndroidRuntime(1328): Process: info.androidhive.slidingmenu,    PID: 1328

 07-06 06:26:49.329: E/AndroidRuntime(1328): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=3
 07-06 06:26:49.329: E/AndroidRuntime(1328):    at    android.util.SparseBooleanArray.keyAt(SparseBooleanArray.java:176)
  07-06 06:26:49.329: E/AndroidRuntime(1328):   at com.androidexample.tabbar.Tab1$1.onItemClick(Tab1.java:45)
 07-06 06:26:49.329: E/AndroidRuntime(1328):    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:299)
 07-06 06:26:49.329: E/AndroidRuntime(1328):    at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1113)
 07-06 06:26:49.329: E/AndroidRuntime(1328):    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2904)
 07-06 06:26:49.329: E/AndroidRuntime(1328):    at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3638)
 07-06 06:26:49.329: E/AndroidRuntime(1328):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
 07-06 06:26:49.329: E/AndroidRuntime(1328):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
 07-06 06:26:49.329: E/AndroidRuntime(1328):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
 07-06 06:26:49.329: E/AndroidRuntime(1328):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
 07-06 06:26:49.329: E/AndroidRuntime(1328):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 07-06 06:26:49.329: E/AndroidRuntime(1328):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
 07-06 06:26:49.329: E/AndroidRuntime(1328):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
 07-06 06:26:49.329: E/AndroidRuntime(1328):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
 07-06 06:26:49.329: E/AndroidRuntime(1328):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `ArrayList` instead. It does not need to have a fixed size and will change every time you add or remove an item.

Instantiate an empty array list as below :

```
ArrayList<String> presentlist = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Then use `add()` in `onItemClick()` :

```
presentlist.add(item)
```

**[EDIT] :**
And use the below loop to get the list of all checked items in the list :

```
for (int i = 0; i<checked.size(); i++){
    if(checked.valueAt(i) == false) continue;
    String item =(String) lv.getItemAtPosition(checked.keyAt(i));
    presentlist.add(item);
}
```

Comment: I added above code still i have error. my logcat after your code, 07-06 07:49:25.629: E/AndroidRuntime(1691): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=2
07-06 07:49:25.629: E/AndroidRuntime(1691):  at android.util.SparseBooleanArray.keyAt(SparseBooleanArray.java:176)
07-06 07:49:25.629: E/AndroidRuntime(1691):  at com.androidexample.tabbar.Tab1$1.onItemClick(Tab1.java:46)
07-06 07:49:25.629: E/AndroidRuntime(1691):  at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:299)

Comment: use len = lv.getCheckedItemCount(); instead of lv.getCount()

Comment: thanks for Your code work for adding. But retriving this list I got error.I use below code,
       for(String s:presentlist){
       Log.d("retrive list",s);
       }

Comment: use - `for(int i=0;i<presentlist.size();i++){Log.d("tag",presentlist.get(i));}` or can use an iterator - `Iterator<String> iterator = presentlist.iterator(); while(iterator.hasNext()){Log.d("tag",iterator.next());}`

Comment: Your welcome. Please do accept the answer if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your String array `String [] present_array;` has a length of 1.
You have to initilaze it with a length

```
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
            long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int len = lv.getCount();
        SparseBooleanArray checked = lv.getCheckedItemPositions();
        present_array = new String[len]; //added this line
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
         if (checked.get(i)) {
      String item =(String) lv.getItemAtPosition(checked.keyAt(i));

     present_array[i]=item;  // ERROR WHEN ADDING STRING ARRAY //

         }          
    }
```

Comment: @user3510102 sorry change the answer must be len not length

Comment: I use len also. But it shows error still now.                      my logcat,   07-06 07:49:25.629: E/AndroidRuntime(1691): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=2
07-06 07:49:25.629: E/AndroidRuntime(1691):  at android.util.SparseBooleanArray.keyAt(SparseBooleanArray.java:176)
07-06 07:49:25.629: E/AndroidRuntime(1691):  at com.androidexample.tabbar.Tab1$1.onItemClick(Tab1.java:46)

Comment: But you get the error here `checked.keyAt(i)` not i the marked line?!

Comment: So you have to use this: `int len = lv.getCheckedItemPositions().size()`

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if i'm wrong but it seems that you are looping all the elements from the `ListView`.

Instead what you (probably) wanted is to loop the elements from `getCheckedItemPositions()`.

You should change your code to this:

```
public class Tab1 extends Activity {
    String [] student_array={"party","sport","music","café","education"};
    List<String> present_array;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    ArrayList<String> presentlist;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tab1);
        final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter= new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked, student_array);
        final ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        lv.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);


        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                                    long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                SparseBooleanArray checked = lv.getCheckedItemPositions();
                int len = checked.size();
                for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                    // Check if it's indeed checked
                    if (checked.get(i)) {
                        int idx = checked.keyAt(i);
                        // Add str
                        String item = (String) adapter.getItem(idx);
                        present_array.add(item);  // ERROR WHEN ADDING STRING ARRAY //
                    }
                }
            }

        });
    }
```

Note how i am checking if the item inside the checked array is actually checked. That's because:

> The function however has a trap that is not documented, is that even
>   you select one item and then deselect, the item is still included in
>   the array

Above is an extract from [Stanley Siu's blog](http://ktatsiu.wordpress.com/2012/08/19/learning-android-how-to-use-getcheckeditempositions-of-listview/)